# distributor certificate for iphone app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m an noob.. am i supposed to create distributor certificate for each new app that i develop..or onesingle distibutor certificate can be reused in different apps that i develop...i was able to launch my first app successfully...will there be any problem if i  reuse the samebundle identifier(mine is.....com.stephen.cwww) in the upcoming app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create another distribution certificate inside the developer portal. For testing you can reuse provisioning profiles like the *. version. As far as distribution goes, you will have to create a 2nd profile for the 2nd app.